# Does clicking when being attacked help block chance?

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

When I'm attacked in Puzzle Quest 2, I've found that I tend to click the mouse button right when the hit lands (a habit likely formed by Super Mario RPG).  I've found that I block attacks more often when I click the mouse than when I don't, but this isn't mentioned anywhere in the introduction.

Am I just experiencing a placebo effect, or does pressing the mouse actually help with block attempts?

Comment: I'm leaving the question platform-agnostic since I assume the same would be the case for the console versions, but if someone has information to hint otherwise, feel free to tag it PC

Comment: My feeling is that it's based entirely on numbers. I'm not sure if you can get a definitive answer short of contacting the dev team, though, given that if there is a possibility to block by clicking, we'd have to somehow determine how big the window is to know whether or not you were actually helping your cause.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis You're probably right.  I guess my question comes down to whether I missed something in the intros that mentioned it.  Or if someone went way overboard and did some statistical analysis of the subject

Comment: Hah I do that too with any turn-based game when attacking.  Also due to SMRPG.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably not.**

There is no mention of this functionality in any of the official tutorials or documentation for PQ2, or anywhere else.  All attack and defense success rates are based on your character's stats.  Also, this functionality would be difficult to replicate on other platforms such as DS (where would I tap)?

Comment: You make a good point about the portability issues a feature like I asked about would cause with the DS.  Unless someone comes up with a more scientific answer, I'll leave this as accepted.

Comment: I don't have my DS version of this anymore, or I'd run through some battles and record my results.